# windows 8 microphone port monitor lag

Tags: software, recording, audio

I'm trying to record my bass through the microphone slot in my PC (via headphone amp output plugged into PC mic input) I set my pc speakers to listen to the mic slot so i can hear what I'm doing. There's a 1/4 or 1/2 second lag for this process. It's less than ideal. How can I make it instant? on Linux it worked fine, am I doing this backwards?

Comment: You could record in Linux, of course. Probably driver latency is your problem. There might not be a way around that with the windows driver(s) for your build-in device(s). You could get an external audio interface with low-latency monitoring.

Comment: Have you tried with ASSIO4ALL drivers? That's what is normally used when going for low latency.

Comment: It depends on what kind of sound driver type your software is designed to use. On an average system without a dedicated soundcard, 15-20 ms latency, not more, is what you should be getting. 

ASIO4ALL as mentioned is your first stop. You could try WASAPI driver type. These are designed to work with generic sound cards.

The best is to use hardware with custom ASIO-type driver.

Comment: I wonder if you could just get a jack splitter for the amp output and run one side to your computer and the other to your headphones. Would that be simpler?